# Components Use form.xml without the use of any legacy classes?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, custom-component

How do I without using any legacy structure or classes, use the Joomla feature wich allows you to define forms in an XML file in the folder:

```
JCOMPONENT_PATH/models/forms
```

And then import and use these forms in a view? I have tried looking for examples, or even looking at Joomla default components like user and contact. It seems though that these components have a mix of JModelBase and JViewLegacy or JModelLegacy. Therefore, find this all very confusing as a newcomer to Joomla development.

Another thing that would be really helpful that I can't seem to find that would also answer this question is a Fully Joomla 3.x only example component with forms (No legacy material used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long story why stuff became legacy. It is still ok to use them as most extensions in the wild are using the legacy library. The extension in core I'm aware of which is using the "new" MVC is com_config. But I guess you are good to go using the legacy classes.

Would like to give you a better answer, but it is how it is :-)